# cant instance class dinamically in my bootstrap logic

Tags: php, frameworks, namespaces, logic

I made a structure to start my php framework and nothing that managed to make it work, since logically it should be possible to instantiate the classes indicated in the "require" but I can not dynamically instantiate them from a string doing:

```
$require_module = 'contact';
$instance = new $require_module;
```

> composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/database": "*",
        "illuminate/routing": "~5.1.16",
        "illuminate/events": "~5.1.16"
    },
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "System\\" : "system/libs/"

    }
  }
}
```

> index.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once './system/sys_functions.php';

    // Load all app modules controller into modules folder
    foreach (read_modules() as $require_module){

            require "./modules/$require_module/controller.php";
            $instance   = new $require_module;

            // output Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'contact' not found in /var/www/html/fsib/test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/fsib/test.php on line 15

    }

?>
```

> modules/contact/controller.php

```
<?php
namespace System\Core;
Class contact extends Fsib_controller
{
}
?>
```

> system/libs/fsib_controller.php

```
<?php
namespace System\Core;

  class Fsib_controller
  {

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution, i can fixed it.

```
    <?php
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
        require_once './system/sys_functions.php';

        // Load all app modules controller into modules folder
        foreach (read_modules() as $require_module){

                require "./modules/$require_module/controller.php";
                $namesp =  "System\Core\\";
                $className  = $module_name;

                $load = $namesp.$className;
                $instance   = new $load;


                // output Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'contact' not found in /var/www/html/fsib/test.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/fsib/test.php on line 15

        }

?>
```